# Counter in mysql doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I'am trying to implement a "most popular searches" function on a web site using a simple counter. The idea is that the first time a search is made, the query is stored in a special table. After that the count number increments by one every time that same search is made. I think I do exactly as I should but the code doesn't seem to work. The `count` value stays on `NULL` in the table. Here's my code. "Searchny" is the table where I store the searches. Any pointers much appreciated!

```
$search_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchny WHERE sok='$sokt'");

if(mysql_num_rows($search_result) == 0 ) { 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO searchny (sok, dt) VALUES ('" . $sokt . "', NOW());"; 
    mysql_query($sql);
}
else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE searchny SET count = count+1 WHERE sok='$sokt'");
}
```

Comment: you should treat the $sokt variable in the same way in the update like in the insert. What is the error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please give us more correct question. With errors please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that `count` is `NULL`. Anything added to NULL is NULL.

Try this query:

```
SELECT NULL + 1
```

The result will be:

```
NULL
```

You could set your default value for the `count` field to `0` instead.

However, here's a simpler way to implement this. Note that I've excluded the date field because I don't know what the requirements for the date are:

```
Table searchny:
---------
sok
count
---------
primary_key (sok)
```

Then do it all in one statement:

```
INSERT INTO searchny (sok, count) VALUES ($sokt, 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1
```

If it's a new sok value, then a new row is inserted and the count is set to 1. If the sok value already exists, then the record's count is incremented by 1.

Comment: Thank you, the prolem with my script was, as you say, that the value was set to null. I will absolutely try your script, it looks much neater!

Answer (score 3):

Probably your count column is `NULL` by default and every `count+1` doesn't make it any less `NULL`. Try either setting default value of one or explicitly set it to one in `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no mistake, so the problem isn't the code.

Is your value NULL or 0 ?

If it is NULL, change

```
 INSERT INTO searchny (sok, dt) VALUES ('" . $sokt . "', NOW());
```

to

```
 INSERT INTO searchny (sok, dt, count) VALUES ('" . $sokt . "', NOW(), 0);
```

Comment: Would make more sense to set it to one upon the first occurence.